# Loop or Vectorize this function for Phylogenetic Tree Clade Dropping

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I have a process which I would like to repeat a known number of times, but with a catch. The first iteration should be with the original dataset, then the next should be with the result of the first, the next with the result of the second, ......

Some background: the dataset is of type `phylo`, so the `append` function inside a `for` loop doesn't make sense to me. Below is the actual code:

```
library(ape)
library(geiger)

clade.dropper <- function(phy, drop.tips) {
new.phy <- drop.tip(phy, tips(phy, drop.tips[1]))
new.phy <- drop.tip(new.phy, tips(new.phy, drop.tips[2]))
new.phy <- drop.tip(new.phy, tips(new.phy, drop.tips[3]))
new.phy <- drop.tip(new.phy, tips(new.phy, drop.tips[4]))
new.phy <- drop.tip(new.phy, tips(new.phy, drop.tips[5]))
new.phy
}
```

I would like to be able to prevent the hard coding of the above and somehow, loop it for a given list containing tip names of a phylogenetic tree to drop.

Thanks!

Comment: if you are using ape, drop.tip already does this: new.phy <- drop.tip(phy,  clade.nums)

Comment: Generally, you should include a `library(your_package)` line in the question and maybe a tag for the package (if one exists), so that people can find out what you're talking about. (I don't know of any `phylo` objects, nor any `drop.tip` functions.)

Comment: It does not seem to be working since drop.tip requires the tip labels of the clade to be dropped. I have attempted using the code you provided and the resulting phylo object did not change. Thus, I resulted to the tips() function to retrieve the tip labels of each clade of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of troubles with your approach - Trees nodes are redrawn every time you subset it - if you are subsetting by node numbers, each time you remove a node, on the next trim, your next node might not be the one you wanted (I have made this painful mistake before).

If you are subsetting by names, you might be ok, but most trees won't have node names.

What we can do is make a list of every tip you want to remove at once, and then trim all at once.

Using `geiger` and `ape`:

```
library(geiger)
library(ape)
```

first load a tree:

```
geo <- get(data(geospiza))
```

the tips function isnt properly vectorized, let's fix that:

```
vtips <- Vectorize(tips, "node")
```

Now we can drop them all at once:

```
todrop <- c(18,20)
drop.tip(geo$phy, unlist(vtips(geo$phy, todrop)))
```

For your example:

```
drop.tip(phy, unlist(vtips(phy, cladenum)))
```

Comment: I just read this comment after I edited the my question. You are absolutely correct; the node names will change when the tree is edited; thus tip names should be used. I have never saw the `Vectorize` function. That is a day saver for sure. Nailed it man!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not exactly familiar with all this phylogeny stuff, but I believe [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) is what you're looking for. Demo on the simple vector example:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4,5);
Reduce(function(current,operand) current+operand,rep(1,6),A);
## [1]  7  8  9 10 11
```

And here's how it would work on phylogenetic data, stealing from the example code on the help page [`?phylo.clades`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/geiger/docs/nodelabel.phylo):

```
library(ape);
library(geiger);
sal <- get(data(caudata));
tax <- cbind(sal$tax[,c('subfamily','family','suborder')],order='Caudata');
tphy <- phylo.lookup(tax,ncores=2);
clade.num <- 1:5;
Reduce(function(phy,clade.num) drop.tip(phy,tips(phy,clade.num)),clade.num,tphy);
##
## Phylogenetic tree with 613 tips and 19 internal nodes.
##
## Tip labels:
##   Batrachoseps_attenuatus, Batrachoseps_diabolicus, Batrachoseps_gavilanensis, Batrachoseps_incognitus, Batrachoseps_luciae, Batrachoseps_major, ...
## Node labels:
##   Caudata, Salamandroidea, Plethodontidae, Bolitoglossinae, Plethodontinae, Spelerpinae, ...
##
## Unrooted; no branch lengths.
```

Comment: You are removing descendants of node1 in the first tree, node2 in the second tree etc. As nodes are redefined on each drop, if OP defined nodes of his initial tree to drop, you will be deleting the wrong ones.

Comment: @jeremycg I gave you +1 because you sound like you know what you're talking about. :)

Comment: thanks, your answer does solve the OPs question, but the way R handles trees means it woudn't be the correct answer.